# create json response without brackets [] in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to send json response as :

```
{"id":13,"user_id":4,"play_list_name":"My Play List12","section":1,"created":"2017-04-14T05:46:47+00:00","status":1}
```

but the webservice is generating json as:

```
[{"id":13,"user_id":4,"play_list_name":"My Play List12","section":1,"created":"2017-04-14T05:46:47+00:00","status":1}]
```

Below is my web service:

```
$response_data=$this->MyPlaylists->findById($id)->toArray();
echo json_encode($response_data); die;
```

However below json_encode is generating valide response:

```
     $response_data=array('response'=>0,'message'=>'This is already added in db');  
echo json_encode($response_data); die;
```

Output:

```
{"response":"already added","message":"This is already added in db"}
```

Comment: `$response_data` is multi dimensional array .. in json_decode use `$response_data[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toArray()` will convert your `Object` in `Array`. So you don't need to add `toArray()` in your result.

```
$response_data=$this->MyPlaylists->findById($id);// without toArray()
echo json_encode($response_data); die;
```

Hope above will work and if not, then try the below code,

```
$response_data=$this->MyPlaylists->findById($id)->toArray();
echo json_encode(
     isset($response_data[0]->id)?
            $response_data[0]:
            array('response'=>0,'message'=>'This is already added in db')

);die;
```